# Ajax form submit doesn't work on 1 page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've a form that I submit with JQuery AJAX. But after I clicked submit, my page is redirect to my form submit.php. I've tried almost everything, but I can't find the bug...

The PHP script is working fine. I only echo once,

HTML:

```
<form class="offerte-form" method="post">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="name" id="naamofferte" name="naam" placeholder="Naam*" required="" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                            <input type="text" class="name" id="naambedrijf" name="naambedrijf" placeholder="Naam bedrijf" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                            <input type="text" class="name" id="adresofferte" name="adres" placeholder="Adres" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                            <input type="text" class="name" id="vestplaats" name="vestplaats" placeholder="Vestigingsplaats" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                            <input type="text" class="name" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                            <input type="email" class="name" id="emailofferte" name="email" placeholder="Emailadres*" required="" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="name" id="telnrofferte" name="telnr" placeholder="Telefoonnummer*" required="" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                            <select class="name" name="offertevoor" id="offertevoor" style="border-radius: 4px;" required>
                                <option value="none">
                                    Selecteer een optie
                                </option>
                                <option value="pallets aanbieden">
                                    Ik wil pallets aanbieden
                                </option>
                                <option value="pallets kopen">
                                    Ik wil pallets kopen
                                </option>
                                <option value="containerservice">
                                    Containerservice
                                </option>
                            </select>
                            <textarea placeholder="Uw opmerkingen" id="messageofferte" name="message" required="" style="border-radius: 4px;"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" value="Verstuur">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    // Get the form.
    var form3 = $('.offerte-form');
    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages3 = $('.offerte-form-message');
    $(form3).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData3 = $(form3).serialize();
    console.log(formData3);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form3).attr('action'),
    data: formData3
    }).done(function(response) {
      // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
      $(formMessages3).removeClass('alert alert-danger');
      $(formMessages3).addClass('alert alert-success');

      // Set the message text.
      $(formMessages3).text(response);

      // Clear the form.
      $('#naamofferte').val('');
      $('#naambedrijf').val('');
      $('#adresofferte').val('');
      $('#vestplaats').val('');
      $('#postcode').val('');
      $('#emailofferte').val('');
      $('#telnrofferte').val('');
      $('#offertevoor').val('');
      $('#messageofferte').val('');

    }).fail(function(data) {
      // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
      $(formMessages3).removeClass('alert alert-success');
      $(formMessages3).addClass('alert alert-danger');

      // Set the message text.
      if (data.responseText !== '') {
          $(formMessages3).text(data.responseText);
      } else {
          $(formMessages3).text('Helaas, er ging iets fout, probeer het opnieuw');
      }
    });
});
```

Sorry for these lines, I needed to add more 'details' but I don't have them.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try with adding the "action" attribute to your form ? :

action="submit.php". Here, your ajax is using this attr, but i may be empty.

Comment: Sorry I am not checking whole code but may you miss action in your form tag

Comment: "my page is redirect to my form submit.php" - yet, nowhere in the code example you show does 'submit.php' show up - so, just how are you getting there????

Comment: url: $(form3).attr('action'), form3 hasn`t an attribute called action... put it and it works

Comment: I Tried but didnt work..

Comment: I've found it, forgot to add }); 
:(

Answer (score 0):

ajax url u call to attr('action') of .offerte-form but I cant see action in your form.check it please.

```
<form class="offerte-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
```